# Regex to Locate Carriage Return Line Feed Followed by anything except an 8 digit number and a |

Tags: regex, notepad++

All.

I have some data with some improper line breaks. I would like to search and replace any  CR LF that is not followed by an 8 digit number and a pipe.

For example:

```
12345678|Text|Text CRLF
123.4567|Text|Text CRLF  
Text|4567890|Text
```

This text above should change to:

```
12345678|Text|Text 123.4567|Text|Text Text|4567890|Text
```

I have tried the following:

```
\r\n([^[0-9]{8}\|])
```

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: You need `\r\n(?![0-9]{8}\|)`, that's assuming you mean LF, not RF.

Comment: Your example is not the same as your description. The first `CRLF` is followed by `123.4567` which is not eight digits alone; it has a `.` in it. The second `CRLF` has `Text` on the next line but you are still showing the deletion of the `CRLF` Please clarify.

Comment: @dawg: From question: `search and replace any CR LF that is not followed by an 8 digit number and a pipe.` seems pretty clear for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\R(?!\d{8}\|)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\R              # any kind of linebreak, you can use \r\n if you want to replace ONLY \r\n
(?!             # negative lookahead, make we haven't after:
    \d{8}           # 8 digit
    \|              # a pipe
)               # endd lookahead
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]